# Bootstrap Tab navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have used a Navigation with 3 Tabs. The First Part and the Third part of the Tab content works fine. The Problem is that when ever i put any content inside the second part of the Tab , the content of the third Tab also starts to display in the Second Tab content area. 
I don't understand why !!
Please Help Any.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">a</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#notify" data-toggle="tab">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">c</a></li>
</ul>


 <div class="tab-content">
    <!--  Part 1 Tab Content-->
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        <table>
           <!-- table Content --> 
        </table>
      </div>

     <!--  Part 2 Tab Content -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="notify">
        <table>
           <!-- table Content --> 
        </table>
      </div>

     <!--  Part 3 Tab Content -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about">
            <!-- about Content --> 
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Could you include an example of what content you are adding?  Your code above works just fine.

Comment: Its Fine Thanks For your reply, I solved it, was a minor mistake.. Actually i was creating a contact list with three sections of information , Tab 1 , 2 and 3 , Tab 1 is for call list, tab 2 for chat and tab 3 for contacts..thatz all